# Arithmetic Progressions of three squares

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I was reading a pdf (*Arithmetic Progressions of Three Squares* by **Keith Conrad**) and I have a question about **Theorem 3.5**. It says that we can use Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression to prove the Theorem, but the proof is on pages 44-45 and I can't find it. Does anyone know the proof with Dirichlet's theorem or have the pages 44-45 from *Arithmetic Progressions of Three Squares* ?

"**Theorem 3.5.**
For rational $ n\neq 0 $, the only nonidentity rational points on $ y^2=x^3-n^2x $ of finite order are $ (0,0), (n,0), and (-n,0) $. "

Comment: It is about the rational points on the torsion, not on the whole curve. Search 'Koblitz nozdr' referenced by https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/3squarearithprog.pdf which shows $E : y^2=x^3-n^2 x$ has $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)=p+1$ when $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, together with the morphism $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}  \to E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and Dirichlet's theorem it should do it

Comment: Thanks. Furthermore, I have a little problem with Corollary 3.3. I can't understand how we can pass between $ nk^2= m^3 - m $ and $y^2= x^3 - n^2x $.

Comment: It is explained juste below $x = nm, y = m^2 k$