# Elliptic Curves (equation)

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Is there a specific method to solve equations like $ y^2 = x^3 - n^2x $ ?
I was reading an example about $ y^2 = x^3 - 49x $ and it says that a solution is  $ (-\frac{63}{16},\frac{735}{64}) $ .
How did he find it?
Thanks

In some papers I saw that if I find a solution $ (x_{0},y_{0}) $ and replace $ x $ with $ x-x_{0} $ and $ y $ with $ y=kx+y_{0} $ I will find all rational solutions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "solving" such an equation.   In what sense does $\left(-\frac{63}{16},\frac{735}{64}\right)$ "solve" $y^2= x^3- 49x$?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to find all rational points $ (x,y) $ giving that $ y^2= x^3 -49x $ or $ y^2= x^3 - n^2x $ in general. This example is from "Arithmetic Progressions of Three squares" by Keith Conrad.

The point I wrote verifies the equation

Comment: Have a look at [Algorithms for finding rational points on an elliptic curve?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/42016/91106) from Mathoverflow.

Comment: The last paragraph sounds really strange. But, are you familiar with [the chord-tangent method of finding more points on an elliptic curve?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)

Comment: @Dr.Mathematics : Do you understand why points of finite order ($E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}$) are very special rational points ? The method to find both are very different. Your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088579/arithmetic-progressions-of-three-squares) is referencing everything you need for $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}$.